# IBM MobileFirst 8 APK Creation

Tags: android-studio, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, mfp

I am creating an APK for release to play store my question is while creating the APK ,i am selecting Generate Signed Bundle or APK but i am not sure if i should use a locally created keystore file by me or it needs some other keystore file the one present in the MFP console runtime settings.

Answer (score 0):

The keystore present in MobileFirst Operations console is for MobileFirst server's use.

To sign your Android application , you should use another keystore.

Refer to the Android documentation for more details on signing your application. Details can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing).